# How to view where the variables are being located in TASM x86?

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86-16, tasm, dosbox

Where do I find the location of variables in TASM **DOSBOX** in turbo-debugger mode?

When I enter `td` I do:

-`alt+V` (= view)
-press `V` (=Variables)
-Go to my variable, press enter on it.
-Then I see: `@087A:0000` , go to the data-segment in the CPU view, and go to `ds:087A` but nothing is there!  (using `CTRL+G`)

This is the variable in assembly:

```
MyVar db 3 dup(6)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: DS:087A and 087A:0000 are likely not the same address. What is in DS?

Comment: @MichaelPetch I assume it's short for DataSegment but I am not sure

Comment: Yes, it is the Data Segment, but what value is in DS. DS  forms part of the address but you don't show us what DS contains. You should be able to find DS listed in the register window along with the values in the other registers.